# Breakpoints in react-elastic-carousel not working

Tags: reactjs, react-elastic-carousel

I installed the react-elastic-carousel and given certain breakpoints to my carousel, but it is not working and I am only being shown one slide.

I wrote the code:

```
const breakPoints=[
  { width: 500, itemsToShow: 1},
  { width: 768, itemsToShow: 2},
  { width: 1200, itemsToShow: 3},
  { width: 1500, itemsToShow: 4}
]
<Carousel breakPoints={breakPoints} enableAutoPlay={true} >
            {eventList.map((event) => {
              if (event.isUpcoming)
                return (<div className="bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500 w-[400px] h-[196px] rounded-xl flex flex-col justify-center content-start p-3" >
                  <div>
                    <h1 className='text-[1.2rem] md:text-[1.5rem] font-[700]'>{event.title}</h1>
                    <p>{event.description.slice(0, 25)}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className='mt-9'>
                    <p>Stay tuned!</p>
                  </div>
                </div>)
            })}
          </Carousel>
```

where I should get 2 slides while seeing from my laptop, but I am still getting 1

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. Following is the snippet which works for me. May be you can fine tune it with your stylesheets. You can debug each piece of the component with console.log

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Carousel from "react-elastic-carousel";

const DUMMY_EVENT_LIST = [
  {
    id: "1",
    isUpcoming: true,
    title: "Upcoming Event 1",
    description: "Sample description 1",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    isUpcoming: true,
    title: "Upcoming Event 2",
    description: "Sample description 2",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    isUpcoming: true,
    title: "Upcoming Event 3",
    description: "Sample description 3",
  },

  {
    id: "4",
    isUpcoming: true,
    title: "Upcoming Event 4",
    description: "Sample description 4",
  },

  {
    id: "5",
    isUpcoming: true,
    title: "Upcoming Event 4",
    description: "Sample description 4",
  },
];

const EventItem = ({ id, title, description }) => {
  console.log("event item called");
  return (
    <div
      key={id}
      className="bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500 w-[400px] h-[196px] rounded-xl flex flex-col justify-center content-start p-3"
    >
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-[1.2rem] md:text-[1.5rem] font-[700]">{title}</h1>
        <p>{description.slice(0, 25)}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-9">
        <p>Stay tuned!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const EventItemList = ({ eventList, breakPoints }) => {
  return eventList.map((event, index) => {
    if (event.isUpcoming) {
      return (
        <EventItem
          key={event.id}
          id={event.id + index}
          title={event.title}
          description={event.description}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return <></>;
    }
  });
};

function App() {
  const eventList = DUMMY_EVENT_LIST;

  const breakPoints = [
    { width: 500, itemsToShow: 1 },
    { width: 768, itemsToShow: 2 },
    { width: 1200, itemsToShow: 3 },
    { width: 1500, itemsToShow: 4 },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Carousel breakPoints={breakPoints} enableAutoPlay={true}>
        <EventItemList eventList={eventList} breakPoints={breakPoints} />
      </Carousel>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```